# Race condition in file struct in xv6 OS

Tags: c, concurrency, operating-system, race-condition, xv6

I'm doing MIT labs for RISK-V xv6 and was working with files in the `kernel/file.c`. I was wondering about how I should arrange spinlocks to safely concurrently modify file struct (see `kernel/file.h` for it). I decided to check how file locking was already implemented in xv6, but then I discovered that there is no locks when modifying shared file struct e.g. `filewrite` and `fileread`.

```
// there is no lock when modifying file flags
int
fileread(struct file *f, uint64 addr, int n)
{
  int r = 0;

  if(f->readable == 0)
    return -1;
  ...
  return r;
}
```

Is there really a race condition because this is toy educational OS or I am overlooking why this is safe to do?

I have checked all references and calls to this function, and still there is no locks. And, of course, this file struct in no way is private to the process modifying it

Comment: `xv6` is/was a real OS. It is the AT&T source code for Unix v6 that was state of the art before 1980. The OS originally ran on a PDP-11. There was only a single processor. So, no need for locking. And, it didn't have special instructions for interprocessor locking anyway. The system only had 64KB of core memory. Unix v6 --> Unix v7 --> System III --> System V. And, it's the progenitor of the `*BSD` FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD. All these versions source code was a fork of the original Unix v6 source code. This is in contrast to Linux/Minix, which were written from scratch.

Comment: Also, if a struct is _only_ accessed from base level (i.e. _not_ within an ISR), we don't need to disable/reenable interrupts either. So, given the context: single CPU and no access from ISR, this is safe to do as is.

Comment: To port this to a multicore CPU, yes, you _would_ need to add spinlocks, mutexes, or rwlocks. This would be a _major_ undertaking to find all the instances and wrap them in lock pairs. And, for all other similar access to [other] structs.